# Ubuntu virtual machine guest-only internet

Tags: virtualbox, security, virtualbox-networking

Disconnecting internet is a great security advise but i want to check my emails. is that possible to  use Ubuntu as host without internet connection while in a guest OS in Virtualbox is able to browse internet ? that way Ubuntu host remain secure

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no. In order for the guest to have access to the internet, the host needs to provide it to the guest.

If you had the internet connected to the host, you might be able to set up the system to only route traffic to the virtual machine process, but that would still leave your host machine open to the internet.

Comment: How do i do that to only let virtual machine processor use the internet ? by iptablaes ? how ?

Comment: So far, I've only really seen solutions for this on Windows hosts. It doesn't look like this is actually possible on Linux.